# Karma cannot load imported files

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I've been struggling for days now with the fact I cannot run any real test with Karma. I can run tests which do not require imports (like basic sanity tests) but as soon I have to import something from my app I get the error:

> system.src.js:1085 GET http://localhost:9876/base/dist/components/test.service 404 (Not Found)fetchTextFromURL @ system.src.js:1085(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1646ZoneAwarePromise @ angular2-polyfills.js:589(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1645(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:2667(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3239(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3506(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3888(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4347(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4599(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:337ZoneDelegate.invoke @ angular2-polyfills.js:332Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:227(anonymous function) @ angular2-polyfills.js:576ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ angular2-polyfills.js:365Zone.runTask @ angular2-polyfills.js:263drainMicroTaskQueue @ angular2-polyfills.js:482ZoneTask.invoke @ angular2-polyfills.js:434
>   angular2-polyfills.js:469 Unhandled Promise rejection: **karma**.error is not a function ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: **karma**.error is not a function(…)consoleError @ angular2-polyfills.js:469drainMicroTaskQueue @ angular2-polyfills.js:498ZoneTask.invoke @ angular2-polyfills.js:434
>   angular2-polyfills.js:471 Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: **karma**.error is not a function(…)

I need to mention :
Example test:

```
import { provide } from 'angular2/core';
import {TestService} from './test.service';
import {
//   beforeEach,
  beforeEachProviders,
  describe,
  expect,
  it,
  inject,
//   injectAsync
} from 'angular2/testing';

 describe('TestService', () => {

  beforeEachProviders(() => [
    provide(TestService, {useClass: TestService})
  ]);
  it('should say hello with name', inject([TestService], (testService: TestService) => {
    expect(testService.name).toBe('Injected Service');
  }));

  it('should say hello with name', () => {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  });

});
```

My project structure Is multi module based like :

[image]

Karma.conf.js:

```
frameworks: ['jasmine'],

files: [
    // paths loaded by Karma
    { pattern: 'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js', included: true, watched: true },
    { pattern: 'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js', included: true, watched: true },
    { pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/bundles/rx.js', included: true, watched: true },
    { pattern: 'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.js', included: true, watched: true },
    { pattern: 'node_modules/angular2/bundles/testing.dev.js', included: true, watched: true },
    { pattern: 'karma-test-shim.js', included: true, watched: true },
    { pattern: 'dist/components/matchers.js', included: true, watched: true },

    // paths loaded via module imports
    { pattern: 'dist/components/**/*.js', included: false, watched: true },

    // paths loaded via Angular's component compiler
    // (these paths need to be rewritten, see proxies section)
    { pattern: 'dist/*.html', included: false, watched: true },
    { pattern: 'dist/styles/*.css', included: false, watched: true },
    { pattern: 'dist/components/**/*.html', included: false, watched: true },
    { pattern: 'dist/components/**/*.css', included: false, watched: true },

    // paths to support debugging with source maps in dev tools
    { pattern: 'src/components/**/*.ts', included: false, watched: false },
    { pattern: 'dist/components/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false }
],

// proxied base paths
proxies: {
    // required for component assests fetched by Angular's compiler
    "/src/": "/base/src"
},
```

karma-test-shim.js:

```
...

System.config({
    packages: {
        'base/src': {
            defaultExtension: false,
            format: 'register',
            map: Object.keys(window.__karma__.files).
                filter(onlyAppFiles).
                reduce(function createPathRecords(pathsMapping, appPath) {
                    // creates local module name mapping to global path with karma's fingerprint in path, e.g.:
                    // './hero.service': '/base/src/app/hero.service.js?f4523daf879cfb7310ef6242682ccf10b2041b3e'
                    var moduleName = appPath.replace(/^\/base\/src\//, './').replace(/\.js$/, '');
                    pathsMapping[moduleName] = appPath + '?' + window.__karma__.files[appPath]
                    return pathsMapping;
                }, {})

        }
    }
});


function filePath2moduleName(filePath) {
    console.log('filePath2moduleName', filePath)
    return filePath.
        replace(/^\//, '').              // remove / prefix
        replace(/\.\w+$/, '');           // remove suffix
}


function onlyAppFiles(filePath) {
    console.log('filePath', filePath)
    return /^\/base\/src\/.*\.js$/.test(filePath)
}


function onlySpecFiles(path) {
    return /.spec\.js$/.test(path);
}
```

Any idea very welcomed !

Comment: And your ts files are compiled into the `dist` folder? Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compile your TS files into the `dist` folder, I think that you have a gap. I would try the following within your `karma-test-shim.js` file:

```
System.config({
  packages: {
    'base/dist': {
        defaultExtension: false,
        format: 'cjs',
        map: Object.keys(window.__karma__.files).filter(onlyAppFiles).reduce(createPathRecords, {})
    }
  }
});

(...)

function createPathRecords(pathsMapping, appPath) {
  var pathParts = appPath.split('/');
  var moduleName = './' + pathParts.slice(Math.max(pathParts.length - 2, 1)).join('/');
  moduleName = moduleName.replace(/\.js$/, '');
  pathsMapping[moduleName] = appPath + '?' + window.__karma__.files[appPath];
  return pathsMapping;
}
```

The following line in your `createPathRecords` function seems strange since you shouldn't have files from `src` but from `dist`.

With this code, I have the following SystemJS configuration generated (`map` block):

```
System.config({
  packages: {
    'base/dist': {
      defaultExtension: false,
      format: 'register',
      map: {
        './comps/my-list': '/base/dist/comps/my-list.js?e9(...)',
        './dist/my-app': '/base/dist/my-app.js?fe(...)',
        './pipes/my-pipe': '/base/dist/pipes/my-pipe.js?78(...)',
        './services/http-service': '/base/dist/services/http-service.js?c1(...)',
        './services/my-service': '/base/dist/services/my-service.js?b1(...)'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

In your case `/base/dist/components/test.service` can't be resolved by SystemJS so I guess that either your `map` block isn't correct or the entry for the `packages` one.

Notice that the entry of the `map` block are relative to the key of the `packages` one. In your case, I guess that you generate the following configuration:

```
System.config({
  packages: {
    'base/src': {
      defaultExtension: false,
      format: 'register',
      map: {
        './components/test.service': '/base/dist/components/test.service.js',
        (...)
      }
    }
  }
});
```

So to debug your problem, I would do the following:

- Logging the `appPath` within your `createPathRecords` function:

  ```
  reduce(function createPathRecords(pathsMapping, appPath) {
    console.log('appPath = '+appPath);
    (...)
  }
  ```
- Logging the whole `map` configuration:

  ```
  console.log(Object.keys(window.__karma__.files).filter(onlyAppFiles).reduce(createPathRecords, {}));
  ```

Based on these hints, you need to adapt your code to have this configuration:

```
{
  './components/test.service': '/base/dist/components/test.service.js',
  (...)
}
```

Comment: I started logging the paths. First: one of the issues is I never reach createPathRecords() because my code crashes somewhere before that . I have added the other methods called in the shim.js. I replaces "src" with "dist" still get the error but at least now the paths for the imported files are ok...

Comment: I finally fixed it ! Thank you Thierry! The problem (as you thought) was the fact that somewhere in teh karma.test.shim.js was a src instead of "dist". That place for me was in onlyAppFiles().  No karma errors anymore.