# Cannot Get Karma To Run My Angular2 Tests

Tags: javascript, angular, karma-jasmine

I feel like I have tried everything. The files are found, even the simplest tests won't run. I show this:

`Chrome 49.0.2623 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
Chrome 49.0.2623 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.003 secs / 0 secs)`

I feel like I've tried everything. I've tried different frameworks, Mocha/Chai - Jasmine, nothing. The debug tab doesn't show anything in chrome when I click it.

Project Dir: http://pastebin.com/1wQubhCt

karma.shim.js: http://pastebin.com/PtPnL82G

karma.conf.js: http://pastebin.com/CU0aqnj6

Example test (obviously expect to fail):

```
import {
  it,
  expect,
  describe,
  beforeEachProviders
} from 'angular2/testing';

describe('myComponent', () => {
  beforeEachProviders([]);

  describe('creation', () => {
    it('should do this', ()=> {
      expect(1).toEqual(2)
    })
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

At this point I recommend using Angular CLI when setting up an angular 2.0 project from scratch. It gives you a functional unit test runner and auto reloading for the website whenever you make a code change.

It removes all the tedious configuration steps you have to go through to set up the project.

Check it out here:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

Answer (score 0):

Running tests within Karma can be a bit painful because of the `karma.shim.js` file. Most of time the problem is in this file.

I think that there is a problem in this file and more particularly in the `onlySpecFiles` function. This should be `/_test\.js$/` instead of `/_test\.ts$/`:

```
function onlySpecFiles(path) {
  return /_test\.ts$/.test(path);
}
```

You could see this question for more details:

- [Karma cannot load imported files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36478554/karma-cannot-load-imported-files/36480586#36480586)

Answer (score 0):

For me this issue was resolved by updating the Angular-CLI:

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```